# R: Pad dates with weekends or bank holidays

Tags: r, time, time-series, xts

Assume the following dataset. I get closing prices for all working days. But I also have missing rows for dates for which there is no observation. How can I add rows equal to each day and date all the way to the present? The reason I need this done is that I need to average by week and having variable time windows renders that impossible.

Here is my code:

```
 library(quantmod)
 from="2012-09-01"
 sym = c("BARC")

 prices = Map(function(n)
 {
  print(n)
  tryCatch(getSymbols(n, src="google", env=NULL, from=from)[, 4], error = 
  function(e) NA)
 }, sym)

 N = length(prices)
 # identify symbols returning valid data
 i = ! unlist(Map(function(i) is.na(prices[i]), seq(N)))
 # combine returned prices list into a matrix, one column for each symbol
 prices = Reduce(cbind, prices[i])
 colnames(prices) = sym[i]
```

If you see the "prices" data frame you will see the point I am making.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a blank `xts` with all the dates first, and then merge with your `prices` object.

```
full_dates <- xts(,order.by = seq(from = start(prices), to = end(prices), by= "day"))
full_prices <- merge(full_dates,prices, all = TRUE)
```

You can also choose to fill forward the missing prices, by the following

```
na.locf(full_prices)
```